# Why does the LOOP instruction result in "value of -288 too large for field of 1 bytes"

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm getting this error when I try to run my assembly code that uses a `loop` command:

> "rip.s:190: Error: value of -288 too large for field of 1 bytes at 497".

This error occurs right when the program is supposed to loop. I tried initially putting "3" in the %ecx register before it enters the loop but I still get the same error. I'm not sure why this is happening so I don't really know how to go about fixing it. I've attached the pertinent code below:

```
    //Other code
    movl    %ecx, -20(%ebp)
    movl    $0, %ecx
    addl    $3, %ecx
    .L24:
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    movl    -32(%ebp), %ebx
    movl    -44(%ebp), %esi
    cmpl    %esi, -52(%ebp)
    movl    %ebx, -48(%ebp)
    jg  .L11
    movl    -52(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %ebx, %edx
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    subl    $2, %edx
    movl    %edx, -40(%ebp)
    movl    %eax, -36(%ebp)
    .p2align 4,,7
    .p2align 3
    .L19:
    movl    -36(%ebp), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    js  .L42
    movl    16(%ebp), %ebx
    cmpl    %ebx, -36(%ebp)
    je  .L11
    .L13:
    movl    -40(%ebp), %ebx
    cmpl    %ebx, -32(%ebp)
    jl  .L14
    movl    -36(%ebp), %esi
    addl    16(%ebp), %esi
    movl    %edi, -60(%ebp)
    movl    %esi, -28(%ebp)
    jmp .L31
    .p2align 4,,7
    .p2align 3
    .L15:
    movl    %edx, -24(%ebp)
    movl    -20(%ebp), %edx
    cmpl    %edx, %ebx
    movl    %edx, -20(%ebx)
    movl    -24(%ebp), %edx
    je  .L38
    .L16:
    movl    -28(%ebp), %edx
    movl    8(%ebp), %edi
    movl    %edx, %eax
    sarl    $31, %edx
    idivl   16(%ebp)
    movl    %edx, %esi
    movl    %eax, -24(%ebp)
    movl    -20(%ebp), %eax
    leal    (%ebx,%eax), %edx
    movl    %eax, -20(%ebp)
    movl    %edx, %eax
    sarl    $31, %edx
    idivl   -20(%ebp)
    movl    (%edi,%esi,4), %eax
    cmpl    $1, (%eax,%edx,4)
    sbbl    $-1, -60(%ebp)
    addl    $1, %ebx
    cmpl    -32(%ebp), %ebx
    jg  .L38
    .L31:
    testl   %ebx, %ebx
    jns .L15
    addl    $1, %ebx
    jmp .L16
    .p2align 4,,7
    .p2align 3
    .L38:
    movl    -60(%ebp), %edi
    .L14:
    addl    $1, -36(%ebp)
    movl    -44(%ebp), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, -36(%ebp)
    jle .L19
    .L11:
    movl    -44(%ebp), %ebx
    movl    8(%ebp), %esi
    movl    -32(%ebp), %edx
    movl    -4(%esi,%ebx,4), %eax
    addl    $1073741823, %edx
    movl    -56(%ebp), %esi
    movl    (%eax,%edx,4), %eax
    movl    -4(%esi,%ebx,4), %ebx
    cmpl    $1, %eax
    adcl    $-1, %edi
    cmpl    $3, %edi
    movl    %eax, -28(%ebp)
    movl    $1, %eax
    je  .L22
    xorb    %al, %al
    cmpl    $2, %edi
    je  .L43
    .L22:
    addl    $1, -32(%ebp)
    movl    %ebx, -24(%ebp)
    movl    -20(%ebp), %ebx
    cmpl    -48(%ebp), %ebx
    movl    %ebx, -20(%ebp)
    movl    -24(%ebp), %ebx
    movl    %eax, (%ebx,%edx,4)
    loop .L24 <--Error occurs right here
    .L9:
    addl    $1, -44(%ebp)
    jmp .L8
```

What is causing the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a compile (assembly) time error, not a runtime one. The `loop` instruction only has a 8 bit signed offset for the jump target, the assembler is trying to tell you that your target is out of range.

You should replace the `loop` instruction with the equivalent `dec ecx; jnz .L24` at the bottom of your loop (which is [recommended anyway for optimization purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently)).  The only difference is that `dec` overwrites EFLAGS.

x86 loops don't have to use the `loop` *instruction*; it's a peephole optimization for code-size when it's convenient to use ECX as a down-counter.  (And comes at the expense of speed on Intel CPUs.)

Comment: Nah I'm required to use the loop command unfortunately. Can you expand on what's causing this error and how to fix it while using a loop?

Comment: If you can't shrink the code, and you must use `loop` then you should `loop` to a nearby trampoline label that subsequently jumps to `.L24`. This is of course totally silly.

Comment: or put the code in a function then call that function on each loop